# Problem Based on Confidence Interval

Tags: probability, self-study, confidence-interval

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{16}$ be a random sample from a $N(4\mu,1)$ distribution and $Y_{1},Y_{2},..,Y_{8}$ be a random sample from a $N(\mu, 1)$ distribution, where $\mu$ is unknown. Assume that two random samples are independent. If you are looking for a confidence interval for $\mu$ based on the statistic $8\bar{X} + \bar{Y}$ where $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are the sample mean based on the given samples. Then, which one of the following statements are true:

A. There exists a $90\text{%}$ confidence interval for $\mu$ of length less than 0.1.

B. There exists a $90\text{%}$ confidence interval for $\mu$ of length less than 0.3.

C. $\mu$ always belongs to its $90\text{%}$ confidence interval.

D. $[\frac{8\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{33} - \frac{1.645}{2\sqrt{66}}, \frac{8\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{33} + \frac{1.645}{2\sqrt{66}}]$ is the unique $90\text{%}$ confidence interval for $\mu$.

**My Approach**

Let $T = 8\bar{X} + \bar{Y}$.

$\bar{X} \sim N(4\mu, \frac{1}{16})$ and $\bar{Y} \sim N(\mu, \frac{1}{8})$.

Then, $T \sim N(33\mu, \frac{33}{8}).$ I assume I have unconsciously used the line **Assume that two random samples are independent.** from the problem here to compute the standard deviation. Please let me know if this is correct.

Now, with this distribution of $T$ in place, I can get one of the confidence intervals as (basis the fact that $\frac{T-33\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{33}{8}}} \sim N(0,1)$):

$[\frac{8\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{33} - \frac{1.645}{2\sqrt{66}}, \frac{8\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{33} + \frac{1.645}{2\sqrt{66}}]$ which is also there in the 4th option but I don't know if it is unique.

So, to rule out this option, I think that I could form some other distributions with $\mu$ as a parameter and get another form of 90% confidence interval. Like one example could be $(\frac{T-33\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{33}{8}}})^2 \sim \chi_{1} ^ 2$. Let me know if this reasoning is correct.

I could also rule out the 3rd option because we are dealing with randomness and probability here, so we can't say that $\mu$ always belongs to the 90% confidence interval.

Now, I know that only one of the options out of A and B are correct. Both have the same language of length piece. So, I could compute the length of my existing CI and see if it fits.

Length = $2\frac{1.645}{2\sqrt(66)} = 0.20$

Now, this length is between 0.1 and 0.3 but how do I prove this exists part. I can see that there exists a CI of length less than 0.3. Should I just from this observation mark the answer as B?

I am not feeling right with this approach, can I see it alternatively with some other approach?

Comment: Option (B) is correct or not, depending on its interpretation.  If by "confidence interval" it means "there exists a 90% confidence interval procedure for which at least one sample has a width of less than 0.3," then obviously it's correct. But "width" might mean "expected width" or it might mean "width for all samples."  Option (D) definitely is not correct.  To see why not, with 5% chance set the confidence interval to $[0,0]$ and otherwise create a 94.74% confidence interval from the sample.  The resulting procedure has a 90% chance of covering $\mu$ but differs from the procedure in (D).

Comment: ... So, although your analysis is thoughtful (and goes well beyond what the author of this multiple choice question likely was expecting), this question looks like it has no valid answer.  The best we can do is to try to "reverse engineer" the intent of the question and guess what it *should* have asked.